# Check a condition in the cells of a column and return a value if the condition is fullfiled, using lambda (PYTHON)

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine the next dataframe

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"col1" : ["a", "b", "z","w", "g", "p", "f"], "col2" : 
["010", "030","500","333","090","050","111"]})
```

I want to use a lambda function to remove the first prefix 0 of the cells in col2.

What I have tried is

```
data["col2"].apply(lambda row: row["col2"][1:] if row["col2"] 
[0:1] == "0" else row["col2"])
```

But is not working, returning the next error

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

So col2 should appear like `10, 30, 500, 333, 90, 50, 111`

Comment: That would still make them strings. you need to convert them to integers.

Comment: I would like to keep them as string. Thanks for the reply

Comment: `data['col2'] = data.col2.astype(int)`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to use 'col2'

```
    data["col2"].apply(lambda row: row[1:] if row[0:1] == "0" else row)
```

[image: output]

Comment: glad to help :) kindly approve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

- [to_numeric()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)-Convert argument to a numeric type.
- [astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)-used to change data type of a series.

**Ex.**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1" : ["a", "b", "z","w", "g", "p", "f"], "col2" :
["010", "030","500","333","090","050","111"]})

df.col2 = pd.to_numeric(df.col2, errors='coerce').astype(str)
#or
#df.col2 = df.col2.astype(int).astype(str)
print(df)
```

**O/P:**

```
  col1  col2
0    a    10
1    b    30
2    z   500
3    w   333
4    g    90
5    p    50
6    f   111
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try regex in python:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"col1" : ["a", "b", "z","w", "g", "p", "f"], "col2" : 
["010", "030","500","333","090","050","111"]})

data['col2'] = data['col2'].apply(lambda x:re.sub(r"^0", '', x))
```

output:

```
  col1 col2
0    a   10
1    b   30
2    z  500
3    w  333
4    g   90
5    p   50
6    f  111
```